# auto update asp.net website bin folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Is there any way to get VS2008 to automatically fill my website bin folder with all the necessary dependencies required for the website?

At the moment it just contains assemblies from the solution but not the third party assemblies I am also using.

Thanks,

AJ

Answer (score 0):

You should set `Copy Local` to `true` in the reference properties.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c.aspx

Comment: Thanks but I already have done this, but the bin folder does not seem to get updated.

Comment: You did a build afterwards, did you?

Comment: Strange...because I just tested it again and it did work for me like expected.

Comment: Could it be because the referenced assemblies are in the GAC?

Comment: No, Copy Local should copy them to the bin directory. You can try with one of the System.xxx classes.

Comment: It could be, look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320295/how-does-copy-local-work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post build events which you can configure in the properties page of a project.

As an example:

[Post build and macros](http://dotnetperls.com/post-pre-build-macros)

[Post build events](http://geekswithblogs.net/dchestnutt/archive/2006/05/30/80113.aspx)