# Does Visual Studio 2010 copy assemblies with "Copy Local = true" on every build?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I have what I hope is a simple question: if I have a file reference set to an assembly on a network share with "Copy Local = true", will that assembly be copied on *every single build*? And if so, is there a setting available that will copy only if the assembly has changed? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No it is not copied every time, only if the shared assembly is newer.

[Here is a really good thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280751/what-is-the-best-practice-for-copy-local-and-with-project-references) about Copy Local best practices and o[ne discussing how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320295/how-does-copy-local-work) (note the GAC discussion).

Answer (score 1):

No it will not be copied every time, only when changed.

You can check this by building, waiting a while, rebuilding and looking at timestamps of the files.