# Web reference not found when distributing application

Tags: c#, .net, binding, assemblies, web-reference

My question is, when an application uses a web reference is one supposed to hand out something extra along with the .exe file?

I have made an application that uses a web reference for dotMailer API (it's for email campaign management).

The application compiles and runs fine on my PC. But tested it on another machine and kept crashing. After loads of troubleshooting I found this is due to calls using the dotMailer API.

I discovered that Fusion logger is the right tool to show me the reason for failing, downloaded and installed it on the test machine and viewed the logs. Some say the operation was successful while others say it failed even though the assembly download was successful. The test machine has web connectivity. I am just starring at the screen frozen don't know how to tackle this.

Is one supposed to copy something from the `Visual Studio project` folder over to the test machine for a web reference to work?

I am using Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your Project -- > Reference --> `Right Click on dotMailer (Your Reference) --> Go to Properties --> Set Copy Local property value as True.` Like Below

While distribution of project, we should set the references `"Copy local Property as True"`. Then only the referred `Dll's` will be copied to publish bin folders.

[image]

[Reference is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew%28VS.80%29.aspx)

[Related Question / Thread is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320295/how-does-copy-local-work)

Comment: I found in another thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320295/how-does-copy-local-work) that this setting doesn't always work the first time, will try setting to true/false a few times see if it has an effect when I copy the .exe over to the test machine. Thanks for the support I am very pleased.