# Assemblies not being copied across from a Nuget Package

Tags: tfs, msbuild, nuget

We have a WCF webservice that is targetting .NET framework 4.0. This WCF, uses a assembly from the same Visual Studio project that in turn uses a couple of Nuget Packages like so below:

```
 <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="4.0.30506.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

This Nuget package is adding two assemblies to the "System.Net.Http" and "System.Net.Http.Formatting" to the project. When this application is getting deployed using TFS Build, for some reason these two assemblies are not getting copied to the bin folder on the server. When I check the "Copy Local" flag for these two assemblies, I see that they are set to TRUE.

I have uninstalled the Nuget packages and installed it again, but doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions as to what could be wrong?

Comment: Are System.Net.Http and System.Net.Http.Formatting in the GAC on the server? Gac references would not be copied in this case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320295/how-does-copy-local-work

Comment: I don't see the two assemblies on the GAC on the server